# image loading (direction)

Tags: images

Usually, all images load from top to bottom. But recently I came across this image, which
loads from bottom to top:

[image]

(Original link here: http://www.ikorka.eu/ikorka.jpg)

Why is this so? What in general determines the direction of image loading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that this file is not really what it seems.

```
> file ikorka.jpg
ikorka.jpg: PC bitmap, Windows 3.x format, 1362 x 1479 x 24
```

so although it is pretending to be a JPEG file it's in actual fact a Windows Bitmap file.  Most browsers don't care about the extension, they just care about the data format, so it really doesn't matter (but it is *very, very* bad practice).

From the Bitmap file format at [fileformat.info](http://www.fileformat.info/format/bmp/egff.htm):

> [Regarding file header structure] If Height is a positive number, then the image is a "bottom-up" bitmap with the origin in the lower-left corner. If Height is a negative number, then the image is a "top-down" bitmap with the origin in the upper-left corner.

So in answer to your question, what makes this image different to the others?  It's a Windows Bitmap (masquerading as a JPEG) with a positive height setting which makes it a bottom-up bitmap.